# I can not fill out anything in TextField wrapped with TableRowColumn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textfield, material-ui

I'm using Material-ui and its components are great, but when I try using Table, the problem happens...

```
<TableBody
 displayRowCheckbox={true}
>
 <TableRow>
  <TableRowColumn><TextField hintText="hintText"></TableRowColumn>
 </TableRow>
<TableBody>
```

This is only part of my code. When I fill out something in TextField, the whole row is activated and checkbox is checked. Even I am unable to fill out anything in TextField. I only want to activate checkbox only when I click the checkbox, not the whole row, and then fill out something inside TextField. Is there any properties that I can solve this problem?

Plus, I tried `histStyle={{textAlign: 'center'` in TextField, in order to make histText set in center. However, it is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `onClick` handler to your `TextField` that stops the propagation of the event up to the table cell/row:

```
<TextField onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} hintText="hintText" />
```